# Plugin for creating categories on an entry page in Control Panel

Tags: categories, plugins, control-panel

Is there a plugin that allows to add a category via an entry page? I like how you're able to add categories in Wordpress admin right on a post page, not only via Categories section — this seems to facilitate the categorization of content by editors. It's possible that they'd rather skip the `Assign a category` button than do some extra work to create the required categories, and ability to enter new categories within the entry page would help to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, I don't believe such a plugin exists.

Here's a complete listing of existing Craft plugins:

> https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins

And if you'd like to submit a formal feature request for Craft, you can do so here:

> http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/

It would probably make more sense to request this for Craft's core (rather than a plugin), but you could also request it specifically as a plugin:

> http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285730-plugin-ideas

Comment: There is already a request for the same functionality but with entries themselves. 

http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7203256-ability-to-create-an-entry-from-inside-an-entry-e#comments

Comment: I added this as a feature request for the core. Here's the link: http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/8871952-creating-a-category-from-an-entry-page-in-control. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you use tags maybe? I think they work kind of the same, and u're able to add new ones right in the entry.

Comment: I thought about it, but tags don't support parent-child relationships, and it matters in this case — these categories are to represent languages, language groups and dialects.

Answer (score 0):

They [will add](http://pixelandtonic.com/blog/craft-2.5-beta?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogandtonic+%28Blog+and+Tonic%29) this functionality in Craft CMS 2.5. Problem solved.